# Как написать запрос SQL правильно?

Tags: php, sql, join

Есть три таблицы

```
gallery
    id, ---, ---
events
    id, ---, ---
events_gallery
    id, events_id, gallery_id
```

Делаю запрос

```
SELECT *
FROM events
JOIN events_gallery ON events.id = events_gallery.events_id
WHERE gallery_id in (145, 146)
```

В результате получаю

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [events_id] => 1
        [gallery_id] => 145
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [events_id] => 1
        [gallery_id] => 146
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [events_id] => 2
        [gallery_id] => 145
    )
)
```

Я получаю массив id фотографий выбранных пользователем, далее я должен пользователю вывести события которые совпадают на всех фотографиях. Только совпадающие события на всех выбранных фотографиях. А те которые присутствуют только на некоторых из выбранных фото, выводить не нужно.
Подскажите как написать запрос так, что бы выводились только те записи у которых events_id совпадает?
Хочется получить только эти записи

```
[0] => Array
(
    [events_id] => 1
    [gallery_id] => 145
)
[1] => Array
(
    [events_id] => 1
    [gallery_id] => 146
)
```

Comment: `and events.id = 1`

Comment: Мне не доступен events.id. и он может быть не только 1. Их может быть много но они должны присутствовать у каждого выбранного gallery_id

Comment: Вопрос какой-то невнятный. Что значит "events_id совпадает"? Совпадает С ЧЕМ? Чем вас не устраивает строка [events_id] => 2 [gallery_id] => 145? Почему её не должно быть в ответе? "они должны присутствовать у каждого выбранного gallery_id". **Ну так они и присутствуют**, а в вопросе вы наоборот пишете что их быть не должно. Вы определитесь сначала, что вам нужно, а потом вопрос задавайте. И надо прикладывать содержимое таблиц, желательно в виде дампа. И дамп структуры таблиц

Comment: Я получаю массив id фотографий выбранных пользователем, далее я должен пользователю вывести события которые совпадают на всех фотографиях. Только совпадающие события на всех выбранных фотографиях. А те которые присутствуют только на некоторых из выбранных фото, выводить не нужно.

Comment: Ну вот это гораздо лучше. Нужен запрос с группировкой и having count(*) = количеству фотографий. Скорее всего такой ответ уже есть на сайте

Comment: Учту Ваши исправления по поводу правильности вопросов. Спасибо. И за предложенный вариант тоже спасибо. Сейчас по пробую.

Comment: уфф, нашел наконец-то